# dynamicjasper addConcatenatedReport in a frame

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport, dynamic-jasper

Is it possible to concatenate subReports in a frame placed in the detail band? The goal is to display these subReports and the previous defined elements in the Detail section from a Template.

If I use `dynamicReportBuilder.setTemplateFile(TEMPLATE);` and `dynamicReportBuilder.addConcatenatedReport(subreport);` to insert the subreports in the detail Report, which is loaded from the Template, the previous defined elements in the Detail setion of the report template dissapear. So I am looking for the way to conserve these elements.

Comment: It is not clear in your question what you are trying to do. Can you explain more or maybe create add a picture to try to explain what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: If I use `dynamicReportBuilder.setTemplateFile(TEMPLATE);` and `dynamicReportBuilder.addConcatenatedReport(subreport);` to insert the subreports in the detail Report which is loaded from the Template, the previous defined elements in the Detail setion of the report template dissapear. So I am looking for the way to conserve these elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment it seems like one of two things is happening.

1) You have the sub-report defined in the `Detail` band of the Template file.

In this case it will not work. The `Detail` band in the template file should be empty. If this is the case it is more than likely just ignoring what ever you have there and doing everything else. Check out the [HOW-TO Use custum jrxml templates](http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-use-custom-jrxml-templates/) for more information.

2) `dynamicReportBuilder.addConcatenatedReport(subreport);` does not do what you think it does.

This method appends a second report to the end of the first report. Think of it more as a batch. It is the same thing as setting a value for `JASPER_PRINT_LIST` as an export Parameter when using the Jasper Reports API directly.  Check out the [HOW-TO Add Concatenated Reports](http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/08/how-to-add-concatenated-subreports/) for more information.

---

Dynamic Jasper is a great library, but is really only designed to work with standard tabular reports. It has support for some advanced features, including sub-reports, but it can be limiting.

From what I can find so far, it appears you can only add sub-reports to the Group Headers and Group Footers. So in your case you will probably need to add a Group to report first using `GroupBuilder`. Then you can add the sub-report to the Group Footer. The trick for the group is to make sure that each row will end up being its own group by picking the appropriate fields to group on.

You can look at the code examples in the [HOW-TO Add labels in group header and footer](http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/05/add-labels-in-group-header-and-footer/) to see how to build the groups.

To see how to add sub-reports to the report you can use `DynamicReportBuilder.addSubreportInGroupFooter()` method. For more details about this part and an example check out [HOW-TO Add Subreports (fast way)](http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-add-subreports-fast-way/).

The other option you have is to not use Dynamic Jasper for this particular report, and just use jrxml files and the Jasper Report's API to do it yourself. It may or may not be easier depending on your setup.

Comment: Thanks @jschoen. Your comments are very useful. I am looking for a new approach using Dynamic Reports 2.5.1. When I have the solution I will post here.

Comment: The issue is this: I need to print a Text only in the foot of the first page, and I have tried a lot of code unsuccessfully, because in the following pages print a annoying white space.

Comment: Javier, you need to post some code or something in your question to make clear what it is you are trying to do. Maybe a small running example, that shows the problem. I want to help, but with out code I can not.

Answer (score 0):

By Ricardo Mariaca. This code is the solution, Thank to Ricardo and Dynamic Report

```
    private void build() {
    try {
        JasperPdfExporterBuilder pdfExporterBuilder = export
                .pdfExporter(PDF_FILE);
        JasperReportBuilder jasperReportBuilderMain = report()
                .columns(
                        col.column("Item", "item", type.stringType()),
                        col.column("Quantity", "quantity",
                                type.integerType()),
                        col.column("Unit price", "unitprice",
                                type.bigDecimalType()))
                .setDataSource(createSubreportDataSource())
                // .detail(cmp.subreport(createSubreport()))
                .setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataType.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL);

        JasperReportBuilder jasperReportBuilderDisclaimer = report()
                .setPageFormat(PageType.A4, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE)
                .summary(cmp.subreport(jasperReportBuilderMain))
                .summaryWithPageHeaderAndFooter()
                .setWhenNoDataType(WhenNoDataType.ALL_SECTIONS_NO_DETAIL)
                .columnHeader(
                        cmp.text("first page header").setFixedHeight(50))
                .columnFooter(
                        cmp.text(DISCLAIMER).setStretchWithOverflow(true)
                                .setFixedHeight(250))
                .pageHeader(
                        Templates
                                .createTitleComponent("Ricardo Mariaca Approach"))
                .pageFooter(Templates.footerComponent).show()
                .toPdf(pdfExporterBuilder);

    } catch (DRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private JRDataSource createSubreportDataSource() {
    DRDataSource dataSource = new DRDataSource("item", "quantity",
            "unitprice");
    for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
        dataSource.add("Book", (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1,
                new BigDecimal(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
    }
    return dataSource;
}
```

}